# Interpretation of dummy-coded variable

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients, categorical-encoding

I have a dummy variable, with 1 meaning the years in which an historical event took place and 0 meaning the years in which it didn't take place. I used 0 as the reference category. When the regression output reports a negative coefficient for the historical event variable, am I correct to assume that this means the event had a negative impact on the dependent variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes...a (significant) negative coefficient always means a "negative effect." But it's important to be sure you really know what that *means*.

In basically any regression model, regardless of type (logit, OLS, etc) the regression coefficient of a variable tells you what happens when the variable in question is "increased by one" (holding all other variables constant). For a binary dummy variable, a one-unit increase means "being 1 instead of 0." In an linear regression model (or OLS), which it sounds like you are using, the sign of the coefficient tells you whether the expected value of Y becomes larger (positive coefficient) or smaller (negative) when the variable is increase by one.

Now, in your particular case, your variable is coded this way:

"1 meaning the years in which an historical event took place and 0 meaning the years in which it didn't take place."

A negative coefficient for this variable thus means that you would expect *lower* values of the dependent variable in years when the event took place (relative to the years when the event did not take place). Alternatively, you could *also* interpret this coefficient as telling you that you would expect *higher* values of the dependent variable in years when the event did not take place (in comparison to the years when it did take place). But these are just two ways of talking about the same exact relationship.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thoughtful answers.

Comment: @brian feel free to accept one of the answers here (by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer) if you feel it has sufficiently answered your question.

Answer (score 5):

When dummy coding a variable in a regression, you are effectively comparing a reference group's mean (your intercept) and comparing it to a comparison group's mean (the slope for the other group). This indeed means that if slope is negative for the comparison group, then this means the mean is lower in this group. As a quick example in R, we can check the means of petal widths for each species of plant in the `iris` data:

```
#### Load Library ###
library(dplyr)

#### Get Grouped Means ####
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Mean.Species = mean(Petal.Width))
```

Shown below:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Species    Mean.Species
  <fct>             <dbl>
1 setosa            0.246
2 versicolor        1.33 
3 virginica         2.03
```

Fitting the data to a regression with just this factor (auto-dummy-coded in R):

```
#### Check in Fit ####
fit <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Species,iris)
summary(fit)
```

We get these coefficients:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Petal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-0.626 -0.126 -0.026  0.154  0.474 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        0.24600    0.02894    8.50 1.96e-14 ***
Speciesversicolor  1.08000    0.04093   26.39  < 2e-16 ***
Speciesvirginica   1.78000    0.04093   43.49  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2047 on 147 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9289,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9279 
F-statistic:   960 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Notice they match. The intercept is equal to exactly the mean of setosa. The mean of versicolor is equal to $0.246 +  1.08 = 1.326$. If the coefficient was negative we would subtract these instead to get their means. These become *conditional* if we enter any other predictors into the model, in that they are adjusted to be the means when all other variables are set to zero (and adjusted when those variables increase/decrease).

Comment: +1.  It's gotten so that I can recognize some people's answers before I see the name.  I looked at this one and said to myself "that looks like a Shawn answer" and I was right!  (And that's a good thing!)

Comment: Haha I'm happy to know I have a recognizable style!